# Expected number of self-avoiding walks of a given length in a random graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, expected-value, random-graphs, percolation

Let us consider the following random locally finite (i.e., every vertex has a finite degree) graph:

$\mathbb{Z}^d$ ($d\geq2$) is the set of vertices and any two vertices $v$ and $w$ have an edge between them with the probability $1-e^{-\beta||v-w||^{-1}}$, where $\beta$ is a fixed constant, and $||\cdot||$ is the metric distance. This is basically the model discussed by Duminil-Copin and Tassion in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03050) work. One has to keep in mind that the model is locally finite, so any vertex can admit only finitely many edges attached to it.

Let $N_{v,n}$ be the number of self-avoiding paths of length (graph-distance) $n$, starting from $v\in\mathbb{Z}^d$. I am trying to compute the expectation $\mathbb{E}(N_{0,n})$. My guesses are, it should be of the form $C^n$ for some $C>0$, but I've not been able to prove this yet. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: you want to show it is exactly of that form? or asymptotically ?

Comment: @Asinomás exactly will be better, but even asymptomatically will be of considerable help.

Comment: The paper's author is Duminil-Copin.

Comment: I think something is off with your edge probability. If $v$ and $w$ are far apart (assuming $\beta>0)$ this converges to an edge with probability $1$. Even if you remove the $1-$ in front to make that probability go to zero, you need to explain how to achieve the local finiteness. After a very quick glance at the paper they consider cases where there are no edges between vertices with distance greater than some constant.

Answer (score 1):

A coarse bound, but better than nothing: if $\langle d\rangle$ is the expected degree of a vertex, then the number of self-avoiding walks of length $n$ is between $(\langle d\rangle/2)^n$ and $\langle d\rangle^n$. If $p(\mathbf u)$ denotes the probability of going from a point $\mathbf v$ to $\mathbf u + \mathbf v$, then $$\langle d\rangle = \sum_{\mathbf u \ne \mathbf 0} p(\mathbf u).$$ I will not simplify it because (1) I'm not sure it has a closed form for your probability, and (2) I'm not sure your probability makes sense as stated. But this method works for any translation-invariant set of probabilities.

For the upper bound: if we take the $n^{\text{th}}$ power of the sum above and expand it, we get a sum of all possible terms $p(\mathbf u_1) p(\mathbf u_2) \cdots p(\mathbf u_n)$. When the walk $\mathbf 0$ to $\mathbf u_1$ to $\mathbf u_1 + \mathbf u_2$ to ... to $\mathbf u_1 + \dots + \mathbf u_n$ is a self-avoiding walk, this term is the probability of that walk. Therefore we've summed the probability of all self-avoiding walks. This would give their expected number if we summed nothing else, but our sum also has terms for walks that aren't self-avoiding (those terms may not even be correct probabilities). So $\langle d \rangle^n$ is only an upper bound.

For the lower bound, define $\mathbf u \prec \mathbf v$ if $\mathbf u$ comes before $\mathbf v$ in dictionary order. (That is, if we compare the coordinates of $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ in order, then $u_i < v_i$ at the first place they differ.) We have
$$
   \langle d\rangle/2 = \sum_{\mathbf u \succ \mathbf 0} p(\mathbf u).
$$
If we take the $n^{\text{th}}$ power of *this* sum and distribute, we get a sum of all possible terms $p(\mathbf u_1) p(\mathbf u_2) \cdots p(\mathbf u_n)$ where $\mathbf u_1, \dots, \mathbf u_n \succ 0$. Here, the walk $\mathbf 0$ to $\mathbf u_1$ to $\mathbf u_1 + \mathbf u_2$ to ... to $\mathbf u_1 + \dots + \mathbf u_n$ is *always* a self-avoiding walk: every point comes after all the previous ones in dictionary order. So we get the correct probability of all such self-avoiding walks (and no terms for walks that aren't self-avoiding). However, we don't get *all* self-avoiding walks, so $(\langle d\rangle/2)^n$ is only a lower bound.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the standard proof of Hammersley and Morton would work. You should be able to prove that the $\mathbb{E}(N_{0,n})$ sequence is submultiplicative, leading to the existence of a connective constant, and proving that it is >0 with a counting argument.

You can follow along this article from Tom Hutchcroft : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.09460.pdf